# Residue equality when $z \to 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Let $f,g : \Bbb C^* \to \Bbb C$ a holomorphic function such that $$\frac{f}{g}(z) \to_{z \to 0} 1 $$

Then is it true that $res_0(f)=res_0(g)$ ?

I would say yes because $$\frac{zf(z)}{zg(z)} \to_{z \to 0} 1$$ and it means that $\lim_{z \to 0} zf(z) = \lim_{z \to 0} zg(z) \iff res_0(f) = res_0(g)$.

I feel that there is a problem because the limits in the previous maybe do not exist individually but I cannot think of a counterexample.

Comment: No, for example $f=1/z^2+1/z$ and $g=1/z^2$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I think that this question deserves an answer. Will you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: The result is true if the pole at zero for either is simple but not otherwise as the hypothesis implies that the leading pole coefficients are same, but says nothing about lower order coefficients and the residue is if course the coefficient of $1/z$; the residue formula in the OP works only for simple poles

Answer (score 1):

Your proof would be correct, if we would know that $f$ or $g$ has a pole of order $1$ in $0$. Otherwise the residue of the function $f$ is given by $\operatorname{res}_0(f) = \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{1}{(n-1)!}\left( (\frac{d}{dz})^{n-1} (z^n f(z))\right)$ and not just by $\lim_{z \to 0} zf(z)$, if one knows that $f$ has a pole of order $n$ in $0$. So we would need some more information on derivatives in general.

Answer (score 0):

A third party suggested this triviality should be an Answer:

No. For example let $f(z)=1/z^2+1/z$ and $g(z)=1/z^2$.